# pronunciation rules for words with spelling -th- /θ/ /ð/

Tags: pronunciation, th

Is there a rule to identify which is the correct pronunciation for words with -th- spelling  (mother- think), this /θ/ or this /ð/?

Comment: and then there's *foothill*

Answer (score 9):

As Matt says, there are no strict rules.  However, there are patterns:

- word-initial  is usually /θ/ (thin, think) except in function words (this)
- word-medial  is usually /ð/ in native vocabulary (mother) and /θ/ in loanwords (Athens)
- word-final  is usually /ð/ in verbs (breathe) and /θ/ in nouns (breath).

Comment: RE: the first bullet, how do you define a function word?

Comment: It's easier to list examples than to give a rigorous definition: than that the thee their theirs them themselves then there these they thine this those thou though thus thy thyself

Answer (score 7):

No. There is no rule - as "th" can become either /θ/ *or* /ð/ depending on the word:

> **thin** /θɪn/
>
> **this** /ðɪs/
>
> **mother** /mʌðər/
>
> **think** /θɪŋk/

On the plus side, the audible difference between /θ/ and /ð/ is so small that normally when speaking getting them mixed up will go unnoticed.